# HTTP status in laravel Response not server

Tags: http, laravel, status

Here I am trying to serve pdf file with the HTTP status code of 418 (I’m a Teapot) and a header value of iron=man, but instead the file is downloaded and renamed as 418.pdf. Something is wrong and I can't seem to know the problem. This example is from Codebright book.

```
Route::get('file/download', function()
{
$file = 'path_to_file.pdf';
return Response::download($file, 418, array('iron', 'man'));
});
```

Comment: Could you tell us a little bit more as to what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate syntax for that function is

```
Response::download(SplFileInfo|string $file, string $name = null, array $headers = array(), null|string $disposition = 'attachment')
```

If you dive into the source code, it's hard-coding a status code of 200 for this function.

I think the easiest way to return a different status code would be to set it before returning it.

```
return Response::download($file, null, array('iron', 'man'))->setStatusCode(418);
```